# Unterschied zwischen “sichern” und “sicherstellen”

Tags: difference, verb

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *sichern* und *sicherstellen*?

> Auf diese Weise ist es leichter zu **sichern,** dass die Reise für die
>   Kinder ihren Zweck erfüllt und zur Entfaltung ihres Kindes beiträgt.

Im DWDS werden beide Begriffe mit »etw. (durch besondere Vorkehrungen, Maßnahmen) gewährleisten« übersetzt. Beide Wörter werden auch mit dem gleichen Ausdruck in meine Muttersprache Tschechisch übersetzt, weswegen ich mir nicht sicher bin, ob es einen Unterschied macht.

Wäre *sicherzustellen* in obigem Kontext auch möglich?

Comment: Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch? Welche Frage bleibt nach dem Lesen der Einträge, eventuell der Übersetzungen, offen?

Comment: Im DWDS sind die relevanten Bedeutungen der Wörter gleichlautend: "etw. (durch besondere Vorkehrungen, Maßnahmen) gewährleisten". Meine Muttersprache ist Tschechisch und die Übersetzungen sind leider gleich. Was also übrigbleibt, ist genau die Frage, die ich gestellt habe.

Answer (score 2):

*Zu sichern* is wrong at that place, it has to be either ***ab***zusichern or (better) *sicherzustellen*.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn man etwas sicherstellt, meint man damit, dass man sich um etwas kümmert. Z. B. "Ich habe sicher gestellt, dass das funktioniert" oder auch "Sie hat sicher gestellt, dass mein Antrag schnellstmöglich bearbeitet wird". Hier kann man "Sicherstellen" nicht durch "Sichern" austauschen.

Mit "Sichern" kann man einerseits meinen, dass man die Sicherheit erhöht, z. B.: "Der Gurt sichert den Autofahrer zusätzlich." Hier kann man nicht "sicherstellen" schreiben, außer man konstruiert den Satz komplett um (z. B. "Der Gurt stellt sicher, dass der Autofahrer zusätzlich geschützt wird"). Ferner kann man mit "Sichern" auch "Ergattern" meinen. Z. B. "Ich habe uns die Konzertkarten gesichert, bevor sie ausverkauft waren".

Comment: Du meinst sicher "sichergestellt" statt "sicher gestellt" i.d 2. Zeile